# How to ensure message will be there for 10 minutes in queue

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I have two applications `App1 Console app` and `App2 Azure func App`

`App1 is for enroll new customer` 
`App2 is for activate account for new customer`

We `need to ensure that each message that App1 sends is stored in a queue for 10 minutes before App2 uses the message`

From App1 I'm taking inputs like customer-id , customer-name and send this message to queue.
using simple code -

```
// Create a new message to send to the queue
                    string messageBody = $"Message {i}";
                    var message = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messageBody));

                    // Write the body of the message to the console
                    Console.WriteLine($"Sending message: {messageBody}");

                    // Send the message to the queue
                    await queueClient.SendAsync(message);
```

do i need to add any setting for 10 minutes scenario?

From App2 I need to read this message but need to ensure for 10 minutes before App2 uses the message.
How to achieve this to ensure message there for 10 minutes in queue.

When i search on stackoverflow i found this 
`If a message is added with a 5 minute timeout it will only be processed after that.`
 it means while sending message i need to set something ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure Queues - Functions - Message Visibility - Workers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42557861/azure-queues-functions-message-visibility-workers)

Comment: yes i'm using azure function app for waiting but i'm not sure how to wait for 10 minutes before read? I found something like If a message is added with a 5 minute timeout it will only be processed after that. in given duplicate answer ? what should i do?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the message should be hidden for 10 minutes before it can be consumed by any clients. Am I correct?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're looking for [Scheduled messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-sequencing#scheduled-messages).

> You can submit messages to a queue or topic for delayed processing; for example, to schedule a job to become available for processing by a system at a certain time. This capability realizes a reliable distributed time-based scheduler.
>
> Scheduled messages do not materialize in the queue until the defined enqueue time. Before that time, scheduled messages can be canceled. Cancellation deletes the message.
>
> You can schedule messages either by setting the [ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.message.scheduledenqueuetimeutc) property when sending a message through the regular send path, or explicitly with the [ScheduleMessageAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.queueclient.schedulemessageasync#Microsoft_Azure_ServiceBus_QueueClient_ScheduleMessageAsync_Microsoft_Azure_ServiceBus_Message_System_DateTimeOffset_) API. The latter immediately returns the scheduled message's SequenceNumber, which you can later use to cancel the scheduled message if needed. Scheduled messages and their sequence numbers can also be discovered using [message browsing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-browsing).